# Collect results from recursive call

Tags: c#, .net, recursion

Hi guys i'm having troubles in getting the correct results from a recursive function call

So this is what i have

```
 public IEnumerable<AdProfileDto> GetAdProfilesByGroup(string groupDisplayName)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(groupDisplayName))
            {
                IList<AdProfileDto> adProfiles = null;
                /// start AD query
                using (DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(new DirectoryEntry(AdHelper.path)))
                {
                    /// configure searcher for group
                    /// https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475(v=vs.85).aspx
                    searcher.Filter = string.Format("(&((|(&(objectclass=user)(objectcategory=person))(objectcategory=group)))(cn={0}))", AdHelper.ReplaceSpecialChars(groupDisplayName)); //--> exact search
                    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(new[] { AdHelper.member, AdHelper.category, AdHelper.displayName, AdHelper.accountName });
                    searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;

                    SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();
                    if (result != null) //--> check if there are any results
                    {
                        if (AdHelper.IsGroup((string)result.Properties[AdHelper.category][0])) //--> check if result is a group
                        {
                            ResultPropertyValueCollection propertyValues = result.Properties[AdHelper.member]; //--> get all members for this group : users / groups / both
                            //for (int index = 0; index < propertyValues.Count; ++index) 
                            //{
                                return GetAdProfilesByGroup(AdHelper.GetPropertyCN((string)propertyValues[0])); //--> recursive check each member: user | group, extract displayName first
                            //}
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //return GetAdProfilesByCN((string)result.Properties[AdHelper.displayName][0], 1);
                            adProfiles = new List<AdProfileDto>(); //--> initialize list 
                            adProfiles.Add(GetAdProfilesByCN((string)result.Properties[AdHelper.displayName][0], 1).FirstOrDefault());
                        }
                    }

                    return adProfiles;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
```

The idea is that i get some data from active directory, i have 2 sets i'm interested in: groups and users. A group can have other groups and/or users. The end results should be a list of users for a specific group and, if any, its subgroups
Ex:

> GroupeA : user1, user2 => returns both
>
> GroupeB : groupZ, user1 => result will be user1, user3, user4, user5

```
              |
              -> user 3, user 4, groupT
                                    |
                                     -> user 5
```

any help?
Thank you.

P.S. at the moment i get only one result: after checking with a group that has both users and groups(other users and subgroups as well) the iteration looks like:

> Groupe1 : GroupeA, GroupeB, GroupeC, User1 , User2 ... UserN
>
> GroupeA: UserA1, UserA2 .. UserAN (only)

returns UserA1 and the function ends it does not iterate over the rest of GroupA's users, nor the function resumes after call ended on GroupeB's level

Comment: what´s up with `java`, `c#`, `c++` and `.net`. that´s only one of them shown there.

Comment: yes , sorry for that, i guess the concept would have been the same.

Comment: tags should be directly related to the content of the question, there are usually tags out there specifically for concepts like recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the following stripped down version of your problem:

```
public interface IMember
{
    bool IsGroup { get; }
}

public interface IUser : IMember { }
public interface IGroup: IMember
{
    IEnumerable<IMember> Members { get; }
}
```

A way to enumerate all users of any given group including those belonging to possible nested groups would be the following:

```
public static IEnumerable<IMember> GetAllMembers(this IGroup group)
{
    foreach (var member in group.Members)
    {
        if (member.IsGroup)
        {
            var nestedGroup = member as IGroup;
            foreach (var nestedMember in nestedGroup.GetAllMembers())
            {
                yield return nestedMember;
            }                
        }
        else
        {
            yield return member;
        }
    }
}
```